# Display selected information from JSON

Tags: sencha-touch-2, jsonp

[Example with JSON](http://try.sencha.com/touch/2.0.0/examples/ajax/viewer.html)

How display just special information from JSON? For example in test.json we have

```json
    {
    "productName": "Sencha Touch",
    "version": "2.0 Beta",
    "sampleData": [
        {
            "foo": "bar",
            "desc": "This sample content is loaded from the server."
        }
    ]
}
```

so how on button click XMLHTTP. display only information from"desc"?

**UPDATE**

IF I have such kind if JSON how parse it?

```
[
    {
        "id": 7,
        "answers": [
            {
                "id": 6,
                "answer": "1",
                "isCorrect": false
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "answer": "5",
                "isCorrect": false
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "answer": "3",
                "isCorrect": true
            }
        ],
        "question": "1+2=?"
    },
    {
        "id": 14,
        "answers": [
            {
                "id": 28,
                "answer": "5",
                "isCorrect": false
            },
            {
                "id": 31,
                "answer": "7",
                "isCorrect": true
            },
            {
                "id": 29,
                "answer": "2",
                "isCorrect": false
            },
            {
                "id": 30,
                "answer": "6",
                "isCorrect": false
            }
        ],
        "question": "2+5=?"
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "answers": [
            {
                "id": 13,
                "answer": "3",
                "isCorrect": false
            },
            {
                "id": 11,
                "answer": "5",
                "isCorrect": false
            },
            {
                "id": 14,
                "answer": "6",
                "isCorrect": true
            },
            {
                "id": 12,
                "answer": "7",
                "isCorrect": false
            }
        ],
        "question": "3+3=?"
    }
]
```

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `success` callback of the `Ext.AjaxRequest`, `response.responseText` is just a string that can be decoded using `Ext.decode()`.  So, decode that string and then you can use the result as an object, and access `desc` like you would with any javascript object: `obj.sampleData[0].desc`.

So, replace line 141 of that example with this line:

```
contentView.setHtml(Ext.decode(response.responseText).sampleData[0].desc);
```

Comment: Yes, Thank you. But have a little problem. What if I have little other JSON, see update. Have any idea?

Comment: I try `contentView.setHtml(Ext.decode(response.responseText).question[0]);`, but got error

Comment: You are misreading your object there.  `question` is not an array, the full response is the array.  Try `Ext.decode(response.responseText)[0].question`.